# Navmenu - nav смещается со своего места

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть навигационное меню *Push Jasny Bootstrap*. У него есть *Navbar*. В *Navbar* я делаю *navmenu-nav* -  кнопка *User* с выпадающим меню.
[Push Menu](http://jsfiddle.net/kley/z8c8nL7r/7/)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas="body">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
<ul id = "user_drop" class="nav navmenu-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"> 
            <button  id="btn_user_drop" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" > 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> User <b class="caret"></b>
            </button> 
            <ul id="user" class="dropdown-menu nav">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Настройки</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="logout">Выйти</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Я хочу, чтобы на мобильных экранах navbar прятался. Оставались только кнопки вызова меню. Для этого в css у меня указано правило:

```
    @media (max-width: 768px){
  body {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar {
    right: auto;
    background: none;
    border: none;
  }

}
```

Но при скрытии navbar мое меню *User* смещается в левый угол экрана, при увеличении экрана и появлении *navbar* опять занимает свое правильное положение. Хочу понять почему такое поведение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для нормального(большого) разрешении в bootstrap есть правило:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-right {
    float: right!important;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Поэтому Ваше меню *user* справа при нормальном(большом) расширении(т.е. когда `min-width: 768px`).
Данное правило соответственно не действует для мобильных, т.е. чтобы меню *user* на мобильных было справа(также как и на большом экране) просто добавьте код:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .navbar-right {
        float: right!important;
    }
}
/*или в файле css от bootstrap уберите ограничение @media (max-width: 768px)*/
```

Данный ответ дан по [вашему демо на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kley/z8c8nL7r/7/), код в вопросе и код на *jsfiddle* у Вас отличаются.

**UPD**

Ответ для кода из Вашего вопроса:

Вы можете добавить правило `.navbar{width:100%}`, в данном случае меню *user* не будет смещаться в левую часть экрана в мобильных.

Comment: .navbar{width:100%} то, что нужно. спасибо